# In a bash script, how to run bash functions defined outside?

Tags: bash

For example, the following commands doesn't work.  I wonder how to work around it, thanks.

```
[liuke@liuke-mbp ~]$ function showxx() { echo xx; }
[liuke@liuke-mbp ~]$ showxx
xx
[liuke@liuke-mbp ~]$ cat a.bash 
#!/bin/bash
showxx
[liuke@liuke-mbp ~]$ ./a.bash 
./a.bash: line 2: showxx: command not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to export your functions.  You can either export everything when it's created (my preference) with `set -a`, or you can export the functions individually with `export -f showxx`.  Either will put it into the environment, and child shells will be able to pick them up.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the function to appear in 'scope' of the local process.

When you enter a function onto the command line, it is now 'living' inside the terminal shell's copy of bash.

When you start a script, only variables that are marked with `export` are visible into the new copy of bash that **is running as a child** of the terminal. (We won't get into `export` right now ;-).

To get the function inside your script, you have to define it inside the script.

```
cat a.bash
#!/bin/bash
function showxx() { echo xx; }
showxx
```

OR you can put the function in a separate file and 'source' it (with '.'), so it as if it was inside the file, i.e.

```
 cat    showxx.bfn
 function showxx() { echo xx; }

 cat a.bash
 . showxx.bfn
 showxx
```

The extension .bfn is just something I use to help document what is inside the file, like  bfn= 'bash function'.

The '.' is the source command.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Call your script with a preceeding dot and space.

`. a.bash`

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that your script is `myscript.sh` with the contents below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    export command=$1
    foo() {
        echo "foo function run"
    }
    bar() {
        echo "bar function run"
    }
fi
$command
```

If you execute `./myscript.sh foo` , then the foo function gets executed. If you execute `./myscript.sh bar` then the bar function gets executed.